# How do I enable SEO-friendly URLs in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, seo

I want to do something like `www.mydomain.com/page-slug` point to `www.mydomain.com/custom-pages/view/page-slug`, something like Wordpress. How can I do this in CakePHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to modify the Router in app/config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

to

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

There is a big gotcha to this. If your application has any other controllers besides the pages controller which it will, you will have to explicitly declare the routes to the other controllers *before* the pages controller route like this.

```
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users'));
```

so your router should look something like this

```
Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users'));
Router::connect('/foobars/:action/*', array('controller' => 'foobars'));
//etc...
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

This was my approach for a site that reqiured seo friendly urls from the root /